# My player can't follow the cursor Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PlayerController.LookAtMouse () (at Assets/Scriptes/Player/Move/PlayerController.cs:25)
> PlayerController.Update () (at Assets/Scriptes/Player/Move/PlayerController.cs:16)

Everything works in another project, and when I uploaded this script to a new one, it gives an error, please tell me what to do.

Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    [SerializeField] 
    private float _speed;

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        LookAtMouse();
        Move();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void LookAtMouse()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.up = mousePos - new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        var input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        _rigidbody.velocity = input.normalized * _speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error obviously happens in the `LookAtMouse` method - have you debugged and stepped through that method? Doing so will show you **what** is NULL  - and then the next step would be figuring out *why* it is NULL. Then either make sure that never happens, or find a strategy to deal with a possible NULL situation ....

Comment: The only thing potentially being `null` in your `LookAtMouse` method is `Camera.main` .. make sure your camera is the scene has the tag `MainCamera`